# Selected the wrong option when installing Ubuntu with Windows 11

Tags: boot, partitioning, 22.04

When i was dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 11, i accidentally selected "Install Ubuntu alongside with Windows", what i wanted to do is go to advanced, and select the partition i wanted, now that is late for that, i don´t know if it is  installed in the same partition, or if the partition i allocated before on windows was used to that, the partition i allocated was 24gb, now it says it is allocated, but with 100% disk space, so i i don't know where is Ubuntu installed and if it installed on the partition that i wanted, Ubuntu did not create any other partition on any drive, i only have the two i have created before, i am just scared to remove the new one to re-do it because of the bootloader, if it isn't on the second partition when i manage to delete it, and don't find it, i will be stuck in that boring bootloader screen, just like i did in the past when i didn't know absolutely nothing about dual booting my device.

btw i am using Windows 11 as my second system (installed first).

Comment: You can use gparted and see what partioins are created and where Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: you just saved my life hahaha, found a new 260mb partition, that was hidden on windows, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can check with `gparted` where Ubuntu is installed now.